# Eclipse and class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got some class files that open in Netbeans (with .java extension) but in Eclipse I had the following experience:
At first I could not see the content of the class files with jadclipse and I only saw:
/*jadclipse*/
//Error!

A few days later (without any change to eclipse or ...) I could see them but with errors like the ones bellow:
"Couldn't fully decompile method ...
Couldn't resolve all exception handlers in method ...
Overlapped try statements detected. Not all exception handlers will be resolved in the method ..."

But the other day I ran into the first error that I could not see anything again!!!
OS: Win7
Java: 7
Netbeans 7.1.2
Eclipse version Juno Service Release 1

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you have class files stored with a `.java` extension?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @millimoose. No they are not stored with .java extension, they have .class extension but when I open them in Netbeans they are opened with .java.

Comment: Right. Has this ever worked as you'd expect in Eclipse? The answer could just be that Eclipse's decompiler integration is crap.

Comment: I didn't get your response quite well. Do you mean that I can not fix it?

Comment: I'll admit I'm stretching since I don't use either Eclipse or decompilers any often. I was just asking if this is something that has already worked for you before as expected, in a previous version of Eclipse, not just in Netbeans.

Comment: I am working for the first time with Eclipse as I need it for my work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to know *why* you need the decompiler? JAD hasn't been updated for a while AFAIK so it's simply possible it can't handle Java 7 bytecode, while Netbeans might use a different one that can. (In fact, the errors you mention suggest that it might have trouble parsing the bytecode for Java 7's new `try..catch` statement, but that's a guess.)

Comment: I'm working with a tool that only works with Eclipse and as I was having errors when opening the class files: file not found I thought that there might be a problem with eclipse and the files (that I am quite sure they are fine). On the other hand it was odd that I could see the class files once, but not any more. The reason that I posted this question was because of the error (not found) and I thought that its related to the experience I had in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any help on Eclipse plugin of JAD as I said it didn't work for my class files. So I tried Java Decompiler GUI and it worked very nice, therefore I wanted to share this nice experience so that it might be useful for some body.